# method class with (int [][], int [][], char) help on "char" part and printing wrong values

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods, bluej

**doTheMath(int[][], int [][], char)**
Takes two 2-dimensional integer arrays as parameters and returns a 2-dimensional array of integers. Its third parameter, a character, tells the method which arithmetic operation to perform. It will make a new array that is the same size as the arrays that come in through the parameters. It will use the character parameter to determine which operation to perform when filling the new array. For example, if the character parameter holds a '+' symbol, this method will add the corresponding entries in each array and place their sums in the same position in the new array. It should handle 4 operations: add('+'), subtract('-'), multiply('*'), and divide('/'). If any other character comes in, it should perform the remainder(modulus) operation on the contents of the two arrays.

Thus what I currently have as my code...

```
    public static int [][]doTheMath(int [][]array1, int [][]array2, char arithmetic)
{
    // Declares 2-dimensional array the same size as one in parameters
    int [][]arraySum = new int [array1.length][array2.length];

    // For loop to take each row and column to separately do arithmetic on
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
            if (arithmetic == '+') 
                arraySum [i][j] = array1 [i][j] + array2 [i][j];
            else if (arithmetic == '-') 
                arraySum [i][j] = array1 [i][j] - array2 [i][j]; 

            else if (arithmetic == '*') 
                arraySum [i][j] = array1 [i][j] * array2 [i][j];

            else if (arithmetic == '/') 
                arraySum [i][j] = array1 [i][j] / array2 [i][j];

            else 
                arraySum [i][j] = array1 [i][j] % array2 [i][j];
        }
    }

    // arraySum value is returned
    return arraySum;
}
```

And to call the method in my main would something like this be correct?

```
    // 2-dimensional array created from values taken from doTheMath() method class
    int [][]sum = doTheMath(array1,array2, '+');

    // For loop to print the 2-dimensional array results after arithmetic
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%4s", sum[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

The values I get from printing like this seem to give me wrong values.

```
9 7 2     3 2 5     16  5  7
3 3 3  +  4 1 8  =   6  7  9
4 5 8     2 3 7      9 10 10
```

Array1 and Array 2

```
    // Declared arrays
    int [][] array1;
    int [][] array2;

    // Calls getSize() to get the number for rows and then columns
    int rows = getSize("Please enter number of rows: ");
    int columns = getSize("Please enter number of columns: ");

    // Instantiate input for rows and columns into both double arrays
    array1 = new int [rows][columns];
    array2 = new int [rows][columns];

    // For loop to fill in the rows and column values with random integers
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array1 [i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
            array2 [i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
            System.out.printf("%4s", array1[i][j] + " ");                
            System.out.printf("%4s", array2[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

Comment: Not the actual problem, but you might find it easier to define an enum instead of using a char. You can define a method `apply(int, int)` on that to apply the operation; then you don't have to keep doing the conditional on each element.

Comment: How are you creating `array1` and `array2`? The code you provided is working correctly for me.

Comment: One thing that isn't correct is that the array is initialised using `a1.length` and `a2.length`, but the for loops use `a1.length` twice. Also, this won't work for "non-square" arrays.

Comment: @resueman I have added where I get my array1 and array2 values from.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out if I take this which I thought could be used to print matrices side by side.

```
    // For loop to fill in the rows and column values with random integers
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        array1 [i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        array2 [i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
        System.out.printf("%4s", array1[i][j] + " ");                
        System.out.printf("%4s", array2[i][j] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Changed it to two separate loops gives me the right results.

```
        // For loop to fill in the rows and column values with random integers
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array1 [i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
            System.out.printf("%4s", array1[i][j] + " ");                


        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    // For loop to fill in the rows and column values with random integers
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array2 [i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);               
            System.out.printf("%4s", array2[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```